# Problem with React + Docker (Extremely long loading time)

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, docker-compose

I can’t say after what exactly these problems started, but it started already at the stage of completion of my project, before that everything worked correctly.

**The crux of the problem:** when I do `"npm start"` without docker, the application starts quickly and works correctly, and when I run the application from a docker container, it starts for **several minutes** and does **not automatically reload** when I make changes to the project. Previously, there was no such behavior, the app worked as fast from the docker container as without it.
Here is my docker-compose settings of my react app:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      - HTTP_PROXY=http://backend:8000
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/frontend
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
```

*The problem is exacerbated by the fact that sometimes, due to such a slow work of the docker container containing the react app, docker desktop freezes tightly and cannot stop the running react app image, cannot remove it, and after a reboot, the docker engine cannot start, it has to be completely reinstalled every time.*

How I tried to solve this problem:

1. reinstalled docker - did not help
2. reinstalled nodejs - did not help
3. removed node_modules, package-lock.json and reinstalled them via npm install - did not help
4. ran react container separately from other containers - did not help
5. transferred the entire project to another folder and did everything from scratch from there - did not help
6. tried to start a container with command: `npm start -- --watch` - docker just freezes with no way to kill or stop or remove the running container.

Comment: Can you directly use Node, without Docker?  With the setup you show basically the only thing you're getting from Docker is the Node interpreter, and you can avoid some issues like this by just taking Docker out of the picture.  You don't say what the host OS is, but the bind mount is known to be particularly slow on some platforms, and "live reloading doesn't work" seems to be asked pretty regularly.

Comment: I've experienced docker taking up to 10-12 minutes to build an image of a react application. It would sometimes freeze/crash due to trailing images not being cleared out of the cache. I would recommend running this first `docker image prune` alternatively with flags `-a -f` to clear any other images and to skip confirmation prompt.
Another issue could be due to memory allocation of your docker desktop, by not having enough RAM or assigning too little RAM.